# Converting sentences into predicate logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Let's consider these two statements.

Everything is either complicated or not complicated 
Either everything is complicated or nothing is complicated.

Why would one of these statements be a tautology, and the other one be invalid?

Here's my attempt.

Say C(x) represents it's complicated

1st statement is ∀x [ C(x) v ¬C(x) ], is this right? 
2nd statement is [∀xC(x)] v  [¬∀xC(x)]

I'm not sure if it's correct though, also I can justify why the 1st statement is always true, as it's a disjunction of C(x) and ¬C(x), but I don't seem to be able to justify why the 2nd statement is false. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symbolizations are correct!

The second statement is not necessarily false, but *could* be false ... if some things are complicated *and* some other things are not. This is why the second sentence is not a tautology.

The fact that a sentence is not a tautology does not mean that it *is* false, but that it *can* be false.